# SwipeRefreshLayout with emptyView, refresh spinner blinks

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

I've implemented drag to refresh in a listview using SwipeRefreshLayout. When the list has content everything works fine.

However, if the list is empty the loading spinner doesn't appear when I drag down, instead it briegly blinks after I lift the finger.

The view is refreshed as it should, but the user won't get any visual feedback that drag to refresh is actually implemented.

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Comment: I actually have the same exact problem in my app. Post the xml please